# Is there a commonly accepted design pattern for base methods implementing "early exit" functionality?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, overriding, base-class, virtual-functions

I have a class hierarchy of patterns: patterns are split into simple patterns and compound patterns, both of which have concrete implementations.

Patterns have a `Match` method which returns a `Result`, which can be a `Node` or an `Error`.

All patterns can check for a memoized result when matching. Simple patterns return an error on EOF.

Is there a pattern that allows a more simple way to reuse implemented functionality than mine? Let's say we're using a single-inheritance, single-dispatch language like C# or Java.

My approach is to implement `Match` at pattern level only and call a protected abstract method `InnerMatch` inside it. At simple pattern level, `InnerMatch` is implemented to handle EOF and calls protected abstract `InnerInnerMatch`, which is where concrete implementations define their specific functionality.

I find this approach better than adding an `out bool handled` parameter to `Match` and calling the base method explicitly in each class, but I don't like how I have to define new methods. Is there a design pattern that describes a better solution?

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

> The strategy pattern (also known as the policy pattern) is a software design pattern that enables an algorithm's behavior to be selected at runtime. The strategy pattern
>
> - defines a family of algorithms,
> - encapsulates each algorithm, and
> - makes the algorithms interchangeable within that family.

And perhaps [Chain of Repsonsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

> The chain-of-responsibility pattern is a design pattern consisting of a source of command objects and a series of processing objects. Each processing object contains logic that defines the types of command objects that it can handle; the rest are passed to the next processing object in the chain. A mechanism also exists for adding new processing objects to the end of this chain.

But the Chain of Responsibility would depend more on how you want to handle allowing multiple 'Patterns'(your Objects, not 'design patterns') to be 'processed' in order.

Chain of Responsibility might also be good for allowing you to have dynamic Pattern "sets" that different inputs can be processed with. (Depending on your needs.)

You'll have to encapsulate your input values, but that isn't too big of deal.